# Extracting boundaries of dense regions of 1s in a huge list of 1s and 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, kernel-density

I'm not sure how to word my problem. But here it is...

I have a huge list of 1s and 0s [Total length = 53820].

Example of how the list looks like - 
`[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1...........]`

The visualization is given below.

**x-axis:** index of the element (from 0 to 53820)

**y-axis:** value at that index (i.e. 1 or 0)

**Input Plot-->**

[image: The plots]

The plot clearly shows 3 dense areas where the occurrence of 1s is more.
I have drawn on top of the plot to show the visually dense areas. (ugly black lines on the plot).
I want to know the index numbers on the x-axis of the dense areas (start and end boundaries) on the plot.

I have extracting the chunks of 1s and saving the start indexes of each in a new list named 'starts'.
That function returns a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{'start': 0, 'count': 15, 'end': 16}, {'start': 2138, 'count': 3, 'end': 2142}, {'start': 2142, 'count': 3, 'end': 2146}, {'start': 2461, 'count': 1, 'end': 2463}, {'start': 2479, 'count': 45, 'end': 2525}, {'start': 2540, 'count': 2, 'end': 2543}
```

Then in starts, after setting a threshold, compared adjacent elements. 
Which returns the apparent boundaries of the dense areas.

```
THR = 2000
    results = []
    cues = {'start': 0, 'stop': 0}  
    result,starts = densest(preds) # Function that returns the list of dictionaries shown above
    cuestart = False # Flag to check if looking for start or stop of dense boundary
    for i,j in zip(range(0,len(starts)), range(1,len(starts))):
        now = starts[i]
        nextf = starts[j]

        if(nextf-now > THR):
            if(cuestart == False):
                cues['start'] = nextf
                cues['stop'] = nextf
                cuestart = True

            elif(cuestart == True): # Cuestart is already set
                cues['stop'] = now
                cuestart = False
                results.append(cues)
                cues = {'start': 0, 'stop': 0}

    print('\n',results)
```

The output and corresponding plot looks like this.

```
[{'start': 2138, 'stop': 6654}, {'start': 23785, 'stop': 31553}, {'start': 38765, 'stop': 38765}]
```

**Output Plot -->**

[image: Output plot]

This method fails to get the last dense region as seen in the plot, and also for other data of similar sorts.

**P.S.** I have also tried 'KDE' on this data and 'distplot' using seaborn but that gives me plots directly and I am unable to extract the boundary values from that. 
The link for that question is here ([Getting dense region boundary values from output of KDE plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143998/getting-dense-region-boundary-values-from-output-of-kde-plot))

Comment: So do the ones have to be consecutive? Or it might just be a region along the x-axis with a higher concentration of ones?

Comment: The ones aren't exactly in a pattern. But they do appear consecutive or you can say in chunks. The size of those chunks aren't fixed. @yatu

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Interesting question. I took the opportunity to help out by adding images directly.

Comment: I don't feel like writing an answer, but ... In the hypothesis that your vector of `0` and `1` is a Numpy array, try  `plt.plot((y-0.5).cumsum())` --- as you can see your intervals start (approximately) at a global minimum and end at a global maximum... in `scipy.optimize` you possibly could find a function to identify those extrema.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you'll find plenty of local extrema in the cumulative sum, probably you want to smooth (windowing, running mean etc) the sum to remove them

Comment: @gboffi Thanks for the suggestion! I don't think I fully understand why you used the ``` mylist-0.5 ``` as input to the cumsum function. What is 0.5 used for?

Comment: I have used the 'cumsum()' function on my list and obtain a plot with a line with negative slope and irregularities near the dense regions. But the problem of getting the boundaries from that plot pertains. I have faced the same issue with KDE, have the plot but am unable to extract the boundaries from the plot.

Comment: I have suggested `(y-0.5).cumsum()` because `1`s turn to `+0.5` and `0`s turn to `-0.5`, so that you have a change (an inversion) of the mean slope of the cumulative sum when you have a change of density of ones.  To get the main features (your regions' boundaries) you may have to use a low-pass filter, possibly a simple running mean.

Comment: @gboffi Oh, okay I get it! And how will the mean of the `cumsum()` function output give me 6 values (3 starts and 3 stops)? I'm not very clear on how to implement the low-pass filter. It would be nice if you point me to some documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, you need an answer...

First, the imports (we are going to use `LineCollections`)

```
import numpy as np ; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ;                           
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
```

Next, definition of constants

```
N = 1001 ; np.random.seed(20190515)
```

and generation of fake data

```
x = np.linspace(0,1, 1001)                                                       
prob = np.where(x<0.4, 0.02, np.where(x<0.7, 0.95, 0.02))                        
y = np.where(np.random.rand(1001)<prob, 1, 0)
```

here we create the line collection, `sticks` is a `N×2×2` array
containing the start and end points of our vertical lines

```
sticks = np.array(list(zip(zip(x, np.zeros(N)), zip(x, y))))                                  
lc = LineCollection(sticks)
```

finally, the cumulated sum, here normalized to have the same scale as
the vertical lines

```
cs = (y-0.5).cumsum()                                                            
csmin, csmax = min(cs), max(cs)                                                  
cs = (cs-csmin)/(csmax-csmin) # normalized to 0 ÷ 1
```

We have just to plot our results

```
f, a = plt.subplots()                                                            
a.add_collection(lc)                                                             
a.plot(x, cs, color='red')                                                       
a.grid()                                                                         
a.autoscale()
```

Here it is the plot

[image]

and here a detail of the *stop zone*.

[image]

You can smooth the `cs` data and use something from `scipy.optimize` to
spot the position of extremes.  Should you have a problem in this last
step please ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out for this! I will try this out on my data and see what results I get!