# Getting dense region boundary values from output of KDE plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

This question is an extension/alternate method at trying to solve this question ([Extracting boundaries of dense regions of 1s in a huge list of 1s and 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130596/extracting-boundaries-of-dense-regions-of-1s-in-a-huge-list-of-1s-and-0s))

I have a huge list of 1s and 0s [Total length = 53820].

Example of how the list looks like - [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1...........]

The **visualization** is given below.

**x-axis**: index of the element (from 0 to 53820)

**y-axis**: value at that index (i.e. 1 or 0)

The black lines around the peaks (indicating 1), are the dense regions whose boundary values (start and end values on x-axis) that I want to extract.

**Input Plot-->**
[image: The plots]

I have done a Kernel Density estimation of the indexes (x-axis) and the list of 1s and 0s (y-axis) and I obtain a plot like this:

**KDE Plot-->**

[image: The plots]

I am interested in extracting the values of the x-axis (index number) on y-axis = 1. 
i.e. I would like to extract the boundaries (start and end values) where 1s are most dense 
(***Indicated by black lines on the plot***)

The code for the same is a follows:

```
    path='./'+csv_path+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    mylist = df['Values'] # The huge list with 1s and 0s
    indexes = list(range(len(mylist))) # The corresponding list of indexes of mylist
    ax = sns.jointplot(x=indexes, y=mylist, kind="kde")
    plt.show()
```

I printed out the axes which sns.distplot returns for plotting, which gives me `<seaborn.axisgrid.JointGrid object at 0x7f09d37d5cf8>`

But I am unable to extract the boundary values from that.

I also looked at (https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html) but could not figure out how to use it for my problem here.

Any help would be appreciated :)